# R for loop solution for simple formula

Tags: r, for-loop, formula

I'm stuck with writing this formula in R formula and I really need help. The problem is that i would like to generate a series like the following:

```
x<-seq(-3,3,0.01)
y0<-exp(-abs(x)^0)
y1<-exp(-abs(x)^1)
y2<-exp(-abs(x)^2)
y3<-exp(-abs(x)^3)
y4<-exp(-abs(x)^4)
plot(y[1]~x)
plot(y[2]~x)
etc.
```

Now I would like to write a loop such that:

```
x<-seq(-3,3,0.01)
y[i]<-exp(-abs(x)^i)
plot(y[i]~x)
```

The code I wrote is:

```
par(mfrow=c(3,4))
x<-seq(-3,3,0.01)
for(i in 0:5){
  y[i]<-exp(-abs(x)^i)
}
plot(y[i]~x)
```

and the error message that I receive from R is:

```
> Warning messages:
1: In y[i] <- exp(-abs(x)^i) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Your help is highly appreciated. Its really bugging me, but I just don't get what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Completely agree with EDi's solution. Just to show that you can also solve the bugs in the original code, here is a solution along these lines:

```
par(mfrow=c(3,2))
x<-seq(-3,3,0.01)
# you have to initialize y and it has to be two-dimensional 
y <- matrix(nrow=6, ncol=length(x))
for(i in 0:5){
  # again, y has 2 dimensions and 
  # a matrix only has positive indexes 
  y[i+1,]<-exp(-abs(x)^i)
  # you want to plot from within the loop
  plot(y[i+1,]~x)
}
```

Comment: I would not have come up with that solution. I was looking for a mistake in the formula itself, but I had no idea that it would be necessary to create a matrix. Thxa lot!

Answer (score 1):

I would do it using `expand.grid()`, which gives you all combinations of i and x. No need for a loop here.

```
x <- seq(-3,3,0.01)
i <- 1:4
df <- expand.grid(x, i)
df$y <- exp(-abs(df$Var1)^df$Var2)

require(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = Var1, y = y, col = factor(Var2))) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: @EDIi: Beautiful solution. Nice and simple, like it a lot. However i still have not got to the ggplot package yet, as I'm just getting started with R and still need to develop the basic programming skills.